# Where does tomcat6 hide its cache?

Tags: tomcat6

I have a servlet abc.jar that I copy into `$TOMCAT/webapps`, and everything works fine. Next, I shutdown tomcat, delete the folder abc and the war file. When I restart tomcat, it comes up with error messages like `"Cannot find folder .../abc"`, FileNotFoundException and so on.

My question: How does it know it should be looking for this `"abc"`? I deleted the named directory from "temp" and "work" folders, but it still remembers it. How do I clean all the artifacts? This is tomcat 6, java-1-6-37. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've shut down Tomcat, removed the `$CATALINA_HOME/temp/`, `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/abc/` and `$CATALINA_HOME/work/` folders, and removed the `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/abc.war` file; then the offending remaining reference may be `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/abc.xml` (copied by Tomcat from your web application when it deployed it).

This is not a "cache" as such, but may cause Tomcat to look for folders which no longer exist.

There is a more detailed information at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment. For example:

> Any web application archive file within the Hosts's `appBase` directory that does not have a corresponding context XML descriptor (with a ".xml" extension rather than a ".war" extension) in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine_name]/[host_name]` will be scanned to see if it contains a context XML descriptor (located at `/META-INF/context.xml`) and if one is found the descriptor will be copied to the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine_name]/[host_name]` directory and renamed.

Comment: That was one example of hitting the nail on the head! Thank you, sir.